# Unable to compile vlc jni library using ndk for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, vlc

I'm getting this error after 'ndk-build' command 
fatal error: 'vlc/vlc.h' file not found
 #include 
1 error generated.
make: *** [/Users/..../src/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/vlcjni/libvlcjni.o] Error 1

Thanks in advance :)